# Embed or reference project

Tags: c#, dll, reference

In C#, I'm creating a library that depends on a few other libraries. I can import the source code of those libraries in my code, or I can leave them as is and reference the .dlls. Which practice is better, and which one is faster? So far as a (dis)advantage for keeping it as a .dll is that the end-user of my library is unable to get access to the libraries himself. But that's pretty much as far as I can get on this subject.

Gr.Viller

Comment: Just to be clear, by *"import the source code"*, you mean add these files as links, or copy them to your new project? Or, were you talking about including same "core" projects into different solutions?

Comment: I was talking about copying the files into the project, keeping the same functionality as referencing libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference them, so if a new version is released you don't need to compile your code again, just replace DLLs. Performance issue is neglectable and should not be considered.

Comment: Sounds logical. I was considering it because of the possible performance improvements, but it indeed looks very useful to just be able to replace the DLLs to update parts of the system. Thanks for your quick and clear reply.

Comment: Just as a side note, certain things may still require a recompile. API changes are obvious, but the less obvious one is constants. If your code references a constant in another library, that gets replaced with the value on compile. A change to the constant in a new version of the library will not carry over. This is part of why readonlys and properties are valuable. There are probably more things, and it's worth researching, because DLLs are still the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you include the extenal code, than you get (a little) performance boost. Because it's only one assembly to load. At the otherhand, updating this included code needs some effort.

When you want to benefit from both: try to use IL-Merge as post build action.

Comment: I have used ILRepack (which is the same thing but for mono really) and am very satisfied with the end product being one dll, but only for the release build. So I think I'm going to stick with this. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Because Xaqron's answer is better? I just used ILRepack thanks to your suggestion, not your answer...